# Upgrading py2app with pip breakes it

Tags: python, pip

I upgraded py2app (using pip) and then ran

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/bin/py2applet --make-setup --arch=i386 test.py
```

However I get the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/bin/py2applet", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2797, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: py2app==0.6.3
```

I don't want to use 0.6.3 why is it forcing me to?

Comment: How did you install py2app? with pip or easy_install or something else?

Comment: I used pip to install it (sudo pip --upgrade py2app)

Comment: @Zimm3r Try this `sudo pip install --upgrade py2app`

Comment: Now I get pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.3.1

Comment: Ok downgraded to pip 1.3.1 and ran it fine.

Comment: However I still get pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: py2app==0.6.3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the py2applet shell script has an explicit exit call that checks the py2app version. Updating it to the latest seemed to do the trick. I have two parallel installs of python, the native OS X one and one from MacPorts. Somehow the py2applet script wasn't taken into account after updating the port. I wouldn't recommend this method for other distributions but on a Mac this seems to me a viable solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
__requires__ = 'py2app==0.8'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

sys.exit(
   load_entry_point('py2app==0.8', 'console_scripts', 'py2applet')()
)
```

By the way you can find the version number by importing py2app in the python shell:

```
python
import py2app
py2app.__version__
```

Gives me:

```
'0.8'
```